# why ajax postback not making fileupload textbox empty

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

In my view i have like this :

```
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" />
<input type="button" id="uploadButton" value="Addfile" onclick="uploadfile()" />
```

the javascript is like this :

```
> function uploadfile() {
>       var uploadFile = document.getElementById("uploadFile").value;
>         $.ajax({
>             type: "POST",
>             url: "/controller/actionmethod",
>             data : "uploadFile=" +uploadFile
>             
>           });

    }
```

my problem is why my textbox not empty after this ajax call coming back to same view.

because i need to upload(save file names) multiple files with that ajax call.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload files using AJAX. For example there is the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) which [allows this](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) but behind the scenes it uses a hidden iframe to simulate an AJAX request.

Comment: Yeah, i know that with ajax i'm only taking the filenames, you can see that data : "uploadFile=" +uploadFile, in code .

Comment: @michael, the `input type="file"` is particular. For security reasons you cannot set it's value, and you can read it but only the filename portion, not the path.

Comment: yeah after each ajax call i add to the List of filenames and during submit ,i upload multiple files. you made me question myself.Do i have these file paths after getting back to my view, so that i can upload all files at once.